# Magento 2 Change the content of the luma theme's topmost div

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I need to change the content of the topmost div of the luma theme.

See image below:

[image]

How can I change this?

Comment: what do you want to change?

Comment: I want to remove all it's content and just use the container and position to add something else there. Unless it's easier to hide it and add a new container and position it there?

Comment: you want to remove whole content default welcome message,sign in and create accoutn

Comment: yes, and add something else in it's place. I will be putting the signin somewhere else